# Split sorted list into two lists

Tags: python, list, split, sortedlist

I'm trying to split a sorted integer list into two lists. The first list would have all ints under `n` and the second all ints over `n`. Note that `n` does not have to be in the original list.

I can easily do this with:

```py
under = []
over  = []
for x in sorted_list:
    if x < n:
        under.append(x)
    else
        over.append(x)
```

But it just seems like it should be possible to do this in a more elegant way knowing that the list is sorted. `takewhile` and `dropwhile` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) sound like the solution but then I would be iterating over the list twice.

Functionally, the best I can do is this:

```py
i = 0
while sorted_list[i] < n:
    i += 1

under = sorted_list[:i]
over = sorted_list[i:]
```

But I'm not even sure if it is actually better than just iterating over the list twice and it is definitely not more elegant.

I guess I'm looking for a way to get the list returned by `takewhile` and the remaining list, perhaps, in a pair.

Comment: better use binary search to find the index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct solution here is [the `bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html). Use `bisect.bisect` to find the index to the right of `n` (or the index where it would be inserted if it's missing), then slice around that point:

```
 import bisect # At top of file

 split_idx = bisect.bisect(sorted_list, n)
 under = sorted_list[:split_idx]
 over = sorted_list[split_idx:]
```

While any solution is going to be `O(n)` (you do have to copy the elements after all), the comparisons are typically more expensive than simple pointer copies (and associated reference count updates), and `bisect` reduces the comparison work on a sorted `list` to `O(log n)`, so this will typically (on larger inputs) beat simply iterating and copying element by element until you find the split point.

Use `bisect.bisect_left` (which finds the leftmost index of `n`) instead of `bisect.bisect` (equivalent to `bisect.bisect_right`) if you want `n` to end up in `over` instead of `under`.

Comment: Regarding speed, I'd say it's not really "object comparisons vs pointer copies" but rather "object comparisons vs reference counter increments". And maybe it could be done in O(s) where s is the number of elements in the second part. Using `over = sorted_list[split_idx:]`, `del sorted_list[split_idx:]` and `under = sorted_list` (not sure about the actual complexity of the `del`).

Comment: @KellyBundy: Sure, the reference count increments operate on fragmented memory, so they're likely a little more expensive than the pointer copies. You pay them no matter what though (same goes for the pointer copies), and both of them are trivial next to the cost of comparison. And yes, if you don't need to preserve the original `sorted_list`, you can use it as `under` and `del` the part copied to `over` (`del` from the end of a `list` is implemented as efficiently as it can be; worst case, it reallocs to free space and has to `O(n)` copy the surviving pointers, without touching refcnts).

Comment: Same goes for pointer copies? I don't think so. They're sequential in memory and are processed sequentially. See [this](https://tio.run/##XVDbSsQwEH2frxiQJUmppbWwSGF/wR8oRao7dQN2EpJU8OtrLquuzktyLjOcGfsZLob7R@v2fXFmxaBX0gH1ao0LVwTgKWwWTyiEgGxzM5/jc7UVBBwdXVtVR5jjbyysVLgYh8@oOfneSLKaYG58bJQK0kR4NWfyqQUwlriY93NE8zhMov5DjU@GacIK@VuYG0cf5DxJ9Utp9hSntzW2N6w1Vt7ikgDxLgdcNsbhPskTwL/EvRpyU6JT1qTkzIVOFWK6ci2ZlBrzyWrkbX0hd@rUj9M6zUGKw7F5WHD1KPCAMsSdOupVnecWczGqff8C). Copying the list was ~30 times slower than repetition/reverse/prepend/unprepend (which are similar to pure pointer copying).

Comment: @KellyBundy: Excuse me, I didn't mean your optimization didn't save anything by avoiding pointer copies (my final parenthetical acknowledged that your optimization reusing `sorted_list` does avoid the refcnt manipulation work for half the `list`, and I did say at the beginning of the comment that refcnt manipulation was more expensive than raw pointer copies). I meant that in my code and the OP's proposed solutions (all of which preserve `sorted_list` intact), you'd have to pay both pointer copy and refcnt manipulation costs (and they're cheaper than the comparisons by a significant amount).

Comment: Or [this](https://tio.run/##XY/disIwEIXv5ynmRpKUstgtiAg@SSnS2lQD5odkvNinr5NEBHduknPONwcm/NHdu/4Y4rat0VskY7UhNDb4SG8FkDQ9A55RCAEFi5Nb@HljVYFjots3zQEm/j1MIjnUSCpcfcQLGpfhm5ZOjQpmxhIX6EVOCnI5XP2iE9sDII@4@8fCahpOo2i/rLlaI8C/5l6dCpjt3JaT0lrtPMT79TSZkxbLfS26p511PHfqQ4ZoHEmxO/z8rmgTCtyhJGyw071qS2@FK6i27QU), where copying the sorted list was ~5 times slower than copying the unsorted list. In my understanding, that huge difference is solely due to incrementing the reference counts (and that being cache-unfriendly in the sorted list).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't talking about my optimization idea anymore. I was just referring to your answer talking about pointer copies but not about refcount increments, since I think the latter matter *much* more. And about either of them vs the object comparisons: I'll have to check that. You can see my first experiment included `a.sort()`, which includes comparisons and is about as fast as `a[:]`. Though that's because of an optimization in `sort`, not using regular object comparisons.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Sure, I mention one and not the other, but when it comes to actual Python observable copies the two are equivalent (the process of slicing a `list` inherently both copies pointers from the old `list` to the new slice of it and increments all their reference counts). It does occur to me that the `del` optimization still has to decrement refcnts for all the things it removes, so it's mostly an optimization to save memory unless you *know* `over` will be smaller (in which case you increment all `over`s, then decrement all of them, while leaving refcnts left in `under`  unchanged).

Comment: About `del`: Yes, worst case it reallocs and copies the surviving pointers. But I could imagine both the realloc and the copying being done by some C/OS function that could "cheat" by actually leaving the data in place and just shrinking the allocation in O(1) time. I think I've seen something like that before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242930/discussion-between-shadowranger-and-kelly-bundy).

Answer (score 0):

I would use following approach, where I find the index and use slicing to create `under` and `over`:

```
sorted_list = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8]
n=6

idx = sorted_list.index(n)
under = sorted_list[:idx]
over = sorted_list[idx:]

print(under)
print(over)
```

Output (same as with your code):

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
```

**Edit**: As I understood the question wrong here is an adapted solution to find the nearest index:

```
import numpy as np

sorted_list = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8]
n=3

idx = np.searchsorted(sorted_list, n)
under = sorted_list[:idx]
over = sorted_list[idx:]

print(under)
print(over)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Tank you, but I should have been more descriptive of the problem. I don't actually know what integers are in the list so there might not be an `n` to find the index of.

Comment: How can you determine the point to split if you do not know where? Or should there a default splitting point if `n` is `None`?

Comment: Consider the `sorted_list = [1,3]` and `n = 2`.
In this case `under = [1]` and `over = [3]`. And yet, 2 is not in sorted_list.

Comment: Okay I understand. I added another solution which gives you the correct index also for missing values.